# Rhel osbuild-composer resource-limit-exceeded

Tags: rhel, blueprint, rhel8

I'm trying to use Red Hat Image Builder on a RHEL 8.6 VM with a satellite, but when I try to push a blueprint with `composer-cli blueprints push BLUEPRINT-NAME.toml`, I get an error: `ERROR: Push TOML: Post "http://localhost/api/v1/blueprints/new": read unix @->/run/weldr/api.socket: read: connection reset by peer`. And the service `osbuild-composer.socket` dies:

```
osbuild-composer.socket - OSBuild Composer Weldr API socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/osbuild-composer.socket; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Fri 2023-01-20 03:57:04 CST; 52s ago
   Listen: /run/weldr/api.socket (Stream)
```

This are the logs:

```
Jan 20 04:56:13 myvmname goferd[1135]: [INFO][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] proton:1091 - Connected to internal.server.com
Jan 20 04:56:13 myvmname goferd[1135]: [INFO][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] gofer.messaging.adapter.proton.connection:92 - opened: proton+amqps://internal.server.com:5647
Jan 20 04:56:13 myvmname goferd[1135]: [INFO][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] gofer.messaging.adapter.connect:30 - connected: proton+amqps://internal.server.com:5647
Jan 20 04:56:31 myvmname goferd[1135]: [WARNING][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] gofer.messaging.adapter.proton.reliability:54 - Connection amqps://internal.server.com:5647 disconnected: Condition('amqp:resource-limit-exceeded', 'local-idle-timeout expired')
Jan 20 04:56:41 myvmname goferd[1135]: [INFO][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] proton:1105 - Disconnected, already closed
Jan 20 04:56:41 myvmname goferd[1135]: [INFO][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] gofer.messaging.adapter.proton.connection:131 - closed: proton+amqps://internal.server.com:5647
Jan 20 04:56:41 myvmname goferd[1135]: [INFO][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] gofer.messaging.adapter.connect:28 - connecting: proton+amqps://internal.server.com:5647
Jan 20 04:56:41 myvmname goferd[1135]: [INFO][pulp.agent.f3146f97-75ea-412e-b9e1-be42649eba01] gofer.messaging.adapter.proton.connection:87 - open: URL: amqps://internal.server.com:5647|SSL: ca: /etc/rhsm/ca/katello-default-ca.pem|key: None|certificate: /etc/pki/consumer/bundle.pem|host-validation: None
```

I've tried [reverting to lorax-composer image builder backend](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/composing_a_customized_rhel_system_image/installing-composer_composing-a-customized-rhel-system-image#reverting-to-previous-backend_installing-composer) but it also doesn't work.

```
[user@myvmname demo]$ sudo composer-cli blueprints push dev-golang-1.toml 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 377, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/composer-cli", line 93, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(opts))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/composer/cli/__init__.py", line 68, in main
    result = client.get_url_json(opts.socket, "/api/status")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/composer/http_client.py", line 93, in get_url_json
    r = http.request("GET", url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1365, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 281, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
```

The logs are the same.

I'm completely lost, I don't know how to solve this. Any clue on what could be the issue and how to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by running a simple `sudo dnf update -y`. The RHEL template I used to create the VM was very old, and I didn't know it. With everything up to date, it has worked just fine.

Thank you!